# Override merge without loosing commits in Git

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-strategy

In my master branch There are old commits which are important for me to not loose

I have another branch named beta-release and it lost those old commits since I had to reset its head and then had to add all the changes and make a commit , resulting into a single commit of the whole branch which is the updated version of the whole app !

Now if I merge beta-release (into master) instead of deleting those files that are not present in the beta-release branch , it keeps them , basically just merging but *I want to override without loosing commits of the master branch but making the single commit of the beta-release branch as the newer commit that replaces everything in master*

[Here's my master branch containing old commits which do not reflect the updated version of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Snt.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Snt.png)

[image: Here's my beta-release branch containing new commits which reflect the current version of the app]

I want to override master with beta release branch with history of old commits in master branch

Comment: I'm struggling to follow your description here. Can you give a visual representation of the current and desired commit graph?

Comment: Would rebase help? if you were to rebase `beta-release` on to `master`?

Comment: You say: "There are old commits which are important for me to not loose" in master. But then you say you want: "to override master with beta release branch without history of old commits in master branch". This is confusing.

Comment: Rebasing does not override

Comment: nooooo I want to keep the history in master branch but override changes ! its not even asking me about differences

Comment: I want to do Reset head to the latest commit of the beta-release but that makes master loose all the commits

Comment: I am using test branches to do this

Comment: @WaqasTahir: you can use the `ours` merge strategy. See the linked duplicate. Does it answer your question?

Comment: I will try to do it